# Dump remote SQL Server database and use it locally in a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a website, that is based on ASP.NET and using SQL Server. It is changed every year, as it's mad entirely for a yearly event, and I want to make a website history - to make user able to open the old website in a subdomain.

My problem is that every year I have to restore the database to its original state, and I can't just create another database that would hold the old data. So what I was thinking about was dumping the entire database with its structure into a file (like `.MDF`) and change the `web.config` file, so it'd use the file instead of remote database server.

But when I use SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, I can only export a `.SQL` file. Is it any way to do it, or my approach is wrong?

**Remarks:**

1. Performance is not a problem, the website will be used as a showcase
2. I don't have admin rights on the SQL Server, just data for connections
3. I use Visual Studio 2013 for my (web application) project

Comment: Have you considered taking a ***backup*** before wiping all the data and restoring that backup with a different name?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I have limited numbers of databases I can have at one time

Comment: Seems like you don't really *need* separate databases to do what you're after, anyway. You want the current web site to only work on this year's sales / products etc., right? And you want users to be able to look at old data if they want? Ok, so add a YEAR column to every table, and filter the current web site by the current year, and let the users look at prior years.

Comment: I don't really want to make changes in the database itself, as it'd make me to add additional `where` clasues in every query, that's why I got the idea to dump the base into a file. If it's not possible then well, I'll use some HTML download tool for that

Comment: So you're going to move the data to a file? How is that going to help you? If you want users to be able to query the data, it should be in a database - which means it will have to be attached. Which seems to land you right back at another problem: you can only have so many databases. So what are your users going to do? Download them and run them on their own SQL Server? So why not be nice and give them a backup?

Comment: Adding the Year column is a good suggestion.  It may be a lot of work upfront, but it's a one time permanent fix, and will get you exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. use the separate databases approach in a MDF file
2. use separate tables in the same database eg :`event_2010` ... `event_2014`

Don't forget to  then change the domain each site responds to in IIS to a subdomain like this `2013.myawesomeevent.com` and so forth for each site. And keep each installation in separate folder.